# Unsupported get request public information for a user on FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are try to update users information in our db related to their interests available on facebook. We are able to import data of almost everyone register with us but for the user with fb profile id 100012374975360 we are unable to do so we getting the following error even with fb graph api explorer with the following query params

100012374975360?fields=id,age_range,first_name,last_name,birthday,gender,email,education,devices,cover,about,hometown,currency,context,languages,is_verified,link,locale,location,name,middle_name,meeting_for,name_format,quotes,favorite_athletes,political,security_settings,timezone,sports,relationship_status,work,third_party_id,religion,likes.limit(10),tagged.include_hidden(true).limit(10),interested_in,photos.limit(10)

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '100012374975360' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "FK9+dItscZj"
```

}
}

Can know why it is happening, what is wrong with this user.

Thanks

Comment: Have they granted you permission to get the data? Just because something is public on Facebook.com doesn't mean it is public in the API

Comment: Is that an app-scoped user id you got after the user logged in to your app? Or did you get that id some other way?